# How does one disable the collider of a single tile on a tilemap?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a top-down 2D puzzle game. I'm attempting to create a hole which can be disabled by pushing a boulder on top of it. I'm using a Tilemap for the Holes with a TilemapCollider to detect when something hits it. If the player hits it, they fall in. If a Boulder hits it, it fills.

Current logic is as follows:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
        if (other.tag == "Hole") {
            objectCollider.enabled = false;
            other.enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

This disables the collider for the boulder (correct) and the hole (correct) but also the entire tilemap. How would one go about disabling the collider for a single tile?

Comment: I you created with mesh, just remove that part of mesh in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you created tilemap with mesh, you can just remove that part of mesh. \Because collider cares about whole mesh so only thing you can do is remove that part of mesh or there is trick, If I think same thing as you want, you can make another trigger above whenever object hits.

So when object hits again, it will definitely hit trigger first before hit plane so you can do whatever you want.

Comment: How would one remove it from the mesh during runtime without disabling the sprite renderer for the tile?

Comment: sprite renderer is different problem, I suppose mesh renderer if you want to use it for that. you should make sprite as slice of it I mean there is no way to do it using only one sprite by spriteRenderer.